# error al usar input en vs code con python

Tags: python, string, vscode, input, error404

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola
queria saber porque cuando uso el preview en vs code toma como error el input

Answer (score 1):

esto sucede por retornar el valor de la clase `rectángulo()` de forma erronea: Al momento de imprimir el área muestra el siguiente mensaje `El área es <__main__.calculo object at 0x000001B442E1D888>`.Sin embargo , el código no se declara el momento cuando lo retornas el valor en string por lo que python devolverá por defecto con el método `repr()` que sirve para retornar una representación impresa del objeto en si(Como se ve en el mensaje con su valor hexadecimal).

Para arreglar esto tienes que declarar tu segunda función como `__str__`, que devolvera el valor como string quedando el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
class calculo:
    def __init__(self, base, altura):
        self.base = base
        self.altura = altura

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.base * self.altura)

base = int(input("proporcione la base : "))
altura = int(input("proporcione la altura : "))
rectangulo = calculo(base, altura)

print("el area es", rectangulo)
```